# Testing in TypeScript: multiple issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-testing-library, react-typescript

I'm trying to do 4 very basic tests on a component in React using TypeScript. I'm receiving only one error while trying to access the `src` of an `img`:

```
    test("should show image with correct source", () => {
        render(<Card {...cardProps} />);
        expect(
            screen
                .getAllByAltText<HTMLImageElement>(/cute cat/i)
                .src.toBe(cardProps.image.url)
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLImageElement[]'.ts(2339)
```

Also in the tutorial I'm following all 4 tests should pass, yet none of mine are. So I believe there is some other issues here which I'm sure are all to do with types. Sorry I'm not proficient in TypeScript. I am trying to learn.

Card.tsx

```
import React from "react";

interface IProps {
    cardProps: {
        name: string;
        phone: string;
        email: string;
        image: {
            url: string;
            alt: string;
        };
        favored: boolean;
    };
}

const Card = ({ name, phone, email, image, favored }: IProps["cardProps"]) => {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
                <img src={image.url} alt={image.alt} className="card-img" />
            </div>
            <div className="card-content">
                <h3>{name}</h3>
                <p>{phone}</p>
                <p>{email}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

Card.test.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Card from "../Card";

const cardProps = {
    name: "Sydney",
    phone: "111-111-1111",
    email: "this@that.com",
    image: {
        url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573865526739-10659fec78a5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=830&q=80",
        alt: "cute cat",
    },
    favored: false,
};

describe("Card", () => {
    test("should show name of cat", () => {
        render(<Card {...cardProps} />);
        expect(
            screen.getByRole("heading", {
                name: "Sydney",
            })
        ).toBeInDocument();
    });
    test("should show phone number", () => {
        render(<Card {...cardProps} />);

        expect(screen.getByText(/111-111-1111/i)).toBeInDocument();
    });

    test("should show email", () => {
        render(<Card {...cardProps} />);

        expect(screen.getByText(/this@that.com/i)).toBeInDocument();
    });
    test("should show image with correct source", () => {
        render(<Card {...cardProps} />);
        expect(
            screen
                .getAllByAltText<HTMLImageElement>(/cute cat/i)
                .src.toBe(cardProps.image.url)
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Comment: `getAll...` methods return an _array_ of all matches, hence the type `HTMLImageElement[]`. An array doesn't have a `src` property.

Answer (score 2):

Change `getAllByAltText` method to just `getByAltText`.

The `getAllByAltText` method returns an array, so you won't have access to src

Comment: I've corrected that and that test works but I am still not sure why the other three aren't working?

Comment: `toBeInDocument`, fix for `toBeInTheDocument`